# Unable to perform Log Out from Azure App Proxy url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

My Onpremise app deployed to azure with App Proxy configured.

So, now I have app proxy external  url.
When I browse it, it is redirecting to MS login page, and if Login success able to view Onpremise app.
But how to perform Log out functionality.

I tried as below, but it is not logging off user.

```
protected void LogOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("https://testazureproxyapp.msappproxy.net/?appproxy=logout");
    }
```

How to fix this. Pls suggest.

Comment: Please use this URL to log out the user:  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/logout?client_id=<clientId>&post_logout_redirect_uri=<Logout URL>`

Comment: For the `Logout URL`, you need to register in the portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNI1L.png